# How to hand over params with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I want to hand over params to constructor with MiniTest but I don't know how to do it.

```
# model 
class Avator
  attr_accessor :image, nickname, age

  def initialize(image, nickname, age)
    self.image = image
    self.nickname = nickname
    self.age = age
  end
 end


# test
class ItemImageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is an outline but doesn't really show effort, which is really important. Instead, you need to try, then ask a specific question about the problem that meets the requirements of "[mcve]" and the linked page. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" helps explain too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
class ItemImageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @avator = Avator.new('image', 'Foo', 15)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have any questions, don't be afraid to ask. I will be happy to help :)

Comment: You should help answer well-asked questions. Read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/128421)", https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing.